# How unpack frame ethernet works

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working with socket and try to understand how we can find the good format character to unpack Ethernet Frame.

For example, to unpack Ethernet frame we can do this:

```
struct.unpack("! 6s 6s H", data[0:14])
```

How we know it's "6s 6s H"?

Comment: that is the format of an ethernet header... wireshark has a pretty good explanation for it https://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet, if you're asking about the struct.unpack arguments you can also learn from it here https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html . basically it literally says get first 6 bytes(the destination address) then the next 6 bytes(the source) then the 2 byte etherType

Comment: Ethernet frames are detailed in the IEEE 802.3 specification, so you can build something from that.    [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) also has a good description of the framing.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet packets consist of

- destination MAC address
- source MAC address
- type
- payload
- Padding

MAC addresses are 48 bits or 6 bytes long. Type is a 1 byte field.

If I'm in doubt about those headers, I use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and look at its interpretation. They also have a [wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet) that explains the structure.

In your string, `!` tells to use standard size and network endianness (big endian) when unpacking, `6s` takes 6 characters to build a string for the destination address, `6s` takes the source address and `H` takes an unsigned short for the type.

You find the format characters in [7.3.2.2 of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) and [7.3.2.1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Comment: Besides standard size, `!` means "big endian".